# Как запустить Chrome через Selenium на Debian для Tomcat юзера?

Tags: java, linux, debian, servlet, selenium

**Дано:**

1. Сервлет, запускающий `Chrome` с помощью `Selenium` и что-то там делающий.
2. Разрабатываю на винде, тут всё отлично работает.

**Задача:**

Заставить всё работать и на удалённом сервере на `Debian`

**Проблема:**

Сходу, понятное дело, ничего не работает. Как я понимаю, для обращения к драйверу и самому браузеру юзеру, под которым `Tomcat` запущен, нужны права доступа к файлам и папкам нужным.

**Возможное решение:**

Запускать `Tomcat` из под рута (очень не хочется, ибо это же плохо. Наверное...) или выдать ему таки права к папкам/файлам нужным (драйвер + браузер) (но это, кажется, тоже не очень безопасно).

**Вопрос:**

Как правильно разрулить ситуацию? Таки открыть юзеру под коим `Tomcat` запущен права доступа и будет ли этого достаточно?

Comment: А рассматривали ли вы использование Selenium grid?
Тогда тип браузеров/систему можно возложить на конфигурирование грида.

Comment: @ЗуевВладимир, я про такое даже не слышал... В любом случае дело было 2 года назад и сейчас вопрос уже не актуален)